# R problem Date column stored as Factor R can't convert it

Tags: r

I have downloaded the SP500 data from Yahoo Finance ticker GSPC and am trying to filter it by year, however the Date column is stored as Factor so R can't filter it. Can anyone help me convert it? I tried multiple solutions, but nothing worked.

So far I've used the loaded the lubridate package and used the following code, but all the values just got replaced with `NA`'s.

```
as.Date(SP500$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Then I used the: `SP500$Date <- ymd(SP500$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")` code and again nothing happened. (`SP500` is the name of the data frame that I stored the data in)

Also, tried using just `SP500$Date <- as.Date(SP500$Date)` but R says do not know how to convert it to Date.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Factors are actually numbers. You can use `as.character()` to convert them to characters and then use  `as.Date`. If you are using a `data.frame`, you can prevent it from converting to factors using `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Classes only exist in the environment of a programming language. What likely happened was that your data (perhaps a .csv file?) got interpreted as `factor` by R during reading.

Everything you're trying to do here can be accomplished using the `base` library in R (meaning you don't need to import anything).

If you're dealing with dates:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

If you're dealing with datetimes:

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

(obviously the specific format may vary; [see list](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/))

Occasionally, coercion in R may act finicky. The `format` parameter is somewhat unforgiving of errors. I personally frequently mistake `-` for `/`, or conflate `"%Y-%m-%d"` with `"%d-%m-%Y"` causing the operation to throw an error. Obviously, if the format isn't consistent in your data, instances that can't be described by the specific `format` you supplied will result in `NA`s.

Sometimes your dates are actually integers (e.g. `20181111`); in this case, you may need to supply `'1970-01-01'` to the `origin` parameter of `as.Date()`. For example, if you are iterating through a vector of `Date`s using a for loop, R won't honour the class of passed `Date`s and will convert them to `integer`s.

It may sound like a bandaid solution, but class coercions *from* common types like `character` are usually written well; I often pre-emptively coerce the object to `character` when I'm clueless about why my attempt to coerce a class failed.